# Duplicate layers in multiple artboards - Photoshop 2019

Tags: javascript, copy, photoshop, paste, layer

Is there any way or script  to copy layer to all artboards in Photoshop?

[image: a busy cat]

Thank you in advance, because I could not find a solution

Comment: Sounds of Night Crickets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Artboards are just specialized layer groups, which can be targeted with the document.layerSets property.  In this working example (tested and working in Adobe PS CC 2019), I make the assumption that there is 1 layer we are copying and each artboard has 1 layer already in it.  For a visual demo, check out this screencast gif: https://www.rebel-ist.com/img/example/duplicateArtboards.gif

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;

// assumes your bottom most artboard in the layer tree contains the layer you want to copy from AKA Artboard 1
var artBoardToCopyFrom = doc.layerSets[doc.layerSets.length - 1];

// assumes there is only 1 layer in this artboard that we need to target
var layerToCopy = artBoardToCopyFrom.layers[0];

// set that layer as the active layer
doc.activeLayer = layerToCopy;

// select all 
doc.selection.selectAll();

// copy the selection
doc.selection.copy();


// loop through each layerSet aka artboard except the last one -- no need to paste an additional copy into the bottom most layerSet
for (var g = 0; g < doc.layerSets.length - 1; g++) {

    // set layer 0 in this group as the active layer -- again assumes there is only one layer in each artboard
    doc.activeLayer = doc.layerSets[g].artLayers[0];

        // select all
    doc.selection.selectAll();

    // paste into selection aka create new layer and paste with mask
    doc.paste(true);
}
```

Comment: Thx! Your scrypt works fine, but creates layer copies. Is it possible to duplicate smart objects? No copy?